# Does a synchronized method have to be external to a class that's using it?

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronized

**Scenario 1.**

A  synchronized method is private and located within a class that implements Runnable

Main.java

```
public class Main { 

Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable); 

. . . 

}
```

MyRunnable.java

```
public class MyRunnable implements Runnable { 

. . . 

private synchronized doSomething { 

}
```

---

**Scenario 2.**

A  synchronized method is public and static and located in the Main class

Main.java

```
  public class Main { 

    Thread thread1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable); 

    public synchronized static doSomething() { 

     }  

    }
```

MyRunnable.java

```
   public class MyRunnable implements Runnable { 

    . . . 


}
```

Question: which of the above scenarios is correct ?

I'm following scenario 2   .  So I have a synchronized method in the Main class. This works fine. When i moved this synchronized method to the MyRunnable class, I didn't see any difference. And this is odd. I was expecting it to fail . `synchronized` prevents from accessing this method simultaneously.

But if I instanciate two instances of a class :

```
MyRunnable runnable1 = new MyRunnable();  
MyRunnable runnable2 = new MyRunnable();
```

Each of this runnables will have it's own `synchronized` , and `synchronized` will have no meaning to the compiler. Do I understand it correctly ?

Comment: I think your understanding is correct, yes. `synchronized` should default to this instance of the class, for non-static methods; if you have two different instances, they will both be able to enter the `synchronized` method at once, because they're looking at different things; the fact that the methods have the same name is irrelevant. Btw, when you say you were "expecting it to fail" - what were you expecting to see? Synchronization is there to avoid thread collisions, which are tough to detect and often luck-dependent.

Comment: Multiple threads could be accessing _the same_ instance, that's when the `synchronized` becomes relevant again.

Comment: `synchronized` is defining *runtime* behavior, ensured by the JVM, its not up to the compiler to do anything with it. That being said, a `synchronized` obejcts *locks on the class*, not the *instance*. I am not sure what exactly your question is, here. What do you expect to fail/happen, and when (rumtime, compile-time)?

Comment: @Edward Peters i apologize for unclear explanation. By expecting it to fail I mean `I was expecting the synchronized become regular method` .  This is exactly what I think `if you have two different instances, they will both be able to enter the synchronized method at once, because they're looking at different things` However I wanted to confirm this with experts first

Comment: @Polygnome "a synchronized obejcts locks on the class, not the instance" - I'm pretty sure you're wrong about that, except in the case of static methods.

Comment: Yes, I wanted to write `static` there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`synchronized` defines *runtime* behavior. It doesn't do anything at *compile-time*.

A `synchronized` method is locked on the *instance* of the object (`this`).
A `static synchronized` method is locked on the `Class` of the object.

This behavior is defined in [JLS §8.4.3.6. `synchronized` Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6)

> A synchronized method acquires a monitor (§17.1) before it executes.
>
> For a class (static) method, the monitor associated with the Class object for the method's class is used.
>
> For an instance method, the monitor associated with this (the object for which the method was invoked) is used.

So, in your *Scenario 1* the method is locked for each individual instance of `MyRunnable`, and in *Scenario 2* the method is locked on the `Main.class` object (which is more or less global, its the same when under the same class loader).

Consider this, in *Scenario 1:

```
MyRunnable runnable = new MyRunnable();
Thread t1 = new Thread(runnable);
Thread t2 = new Thread(runnable);
```

Here, both t1 and t2 use the same instance of `MyRunnable`, which means they won't be able execute `doSomething()` in parallel.

```
Thread t1 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
Thread t2 = new Thread(new MyRunnable());
```

Here, t1 and t2 can execute `doSomething()` *on the instance of `MyRunnable` they were given* in paralell, since they lock on the instance.

In *Scenario 2*, both threads can not execute `doSomething()` in paralell, because they lock in `Main.class` and are loaded by the same `ClassLoader`.